# Using in_groups_of rails helper method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using in_groups_of rails method to display set of records in two columns. Is it possible to apply a css style for each column?

For Example:

```
(1..10).in_groups_of(2).each do |arr|
  puts arr
end
```

This will give [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]].

Is it possible to apply css like this?

```
<article class="column">for one column say [1,3,5,7,9]</article>

<article class="column">for one column say [2,4,6,8,10]</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cycle` with a set of class names to swap the class names back and forth. I think the docs are probably clearer that I could be: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle